# Invalid React Hook within a NPM package

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-hooks, package.json, rollupjs

I have been trying to create a React component library that is contained in an NPM package. I am attempting to use hooks, but I keep receiving the invalid hooks error when I bring the package in via a local install. `npm i C:/pathtopackage/my-package` I created the package with `npm init` and then installed the necessary packages with the correct version types for the target projects.

Here are the package.json files for each:

Package:

```
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "rollup -c",
    "build-watch": "rollup -c -w"
  },
  "author": "me",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "@rollup/plugin-alias": "^3.1.5",
    "@rollup/plugin-babel": "^5.3.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^13.0.5",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "bable-loader": "^0.0.1-security",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "rollup": "^2.58.0",
    "rollup-plugin-babel": "^4.4.0",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.4",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.2"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^21.0.0"
  }
}
```

Target Project:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.57",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.10",
    "@okta/okta-auth-js": "^4.7.2",
    "@okta/okta-react": "^4.1.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.3",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-hook-form": "^6.15.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.2",
    "my-package": "file:../my-package",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is the component that is throwing the invalid hook error:

```
import {useState, useCallback} from 'react';
import {AuthorizationContext} from './AuthorizationContext';

export const AuthorizationProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [roles, setRoles] = useState([]);
    const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState('');

    const authorizationContext = {
        accessToken: accessToken,
        setAccessToken: useCallback((newToken) => setAccessToken(newToken), []),
        roles: roles,
        setRoles: useCallback((newRoles) => setRoles(newRoles), [])
    }

    return (
        <AuthorizationContext.Provider value={authorizationContext}>
            {children}
        </AuthorizationContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

In my search I have attempted to see what is going wrong. I believe it might be a second instance of react running, but I am not sure where or how to fix that or even confirm it. I ran this with [react's](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html#duplicate-react) suggestion: `npm ls react`
And received this output:

```
my-project@0.1.0C:\filepathtoproject\my-project
+-- @material-ui/core@4.11.3
| +-- @material-ui/styles@4.11.3
| | `-- react@17.0.1 deduped invalid: "^16.8.4" from node_modules/@material-ui/pickers
| +-- @material-ui/system@4.11.3
| | `-- react@17.0.1 deduped invalid: "^16.8.4" from node_modules/@material-ui/pickers
| +-- @material-ui/utils@4.11.2
| | `-- react@17.0.1 deduped invalid: "^16.8.4" from node_modules/@material-ui/pickers
| +-- react-transition-group@4.4.1
| | `-- react@17.0.1 deduped invalid: "^16.8.4" from node_modules/@material-ui/pickers
| `-- react@17.0.1 deduped
+-- @material-ui/icons@4.11.2
| `-- react@17.0.1 deduped
+-- @material-ui/lab@4.0.0-alpha.57
| `-- react@17.0.1 deduped
+-- @material-ui/pickers@3.2.10
| +-- react@17.0.1 deduped invalid: "^16.8.4" from node_modules/@material-ui/pickers
| `-- rifm@0.7.0
|   `-- react@17.0.1 deduped invalid: "^16.8.4" from node_modules/@material-ui/pickers
+-- @okta/okta-react@4.1.0
| `-- react@17.0.1 deduped invalid: "^16.8.4" from node_modules/@material-ui/pickers
+-- @testing-library/react@11.2.5
| `-- react@17.0.1 deduped invalid: "^16.8.4" from node_modules/@material-ui/pickers
+-- react-dom@17.0.1 invalid: "^16.8.4" from node_modules/@material-ui/pickers
| `-- react@17.0.1 deduped invalid: "^16.8.4" from node_modules/@material-ui/pickers
+-- react-hook-form@6.15.1
| `-- react@17.0.1 deduped invalid: "^16.8.4" from node_modules/@material-ui/pickers
+-- react-router-dom@5.2.0
| +-- react-router@5.2.0
| | +-- mini-create-react-context@0.4.1
| | | `-- react@17.0.1 deduped invalid: "^16.8.4" from node_modules/@material-ui/pickers
| | `-- react@17.0.1 deduped invalid: "^16.8.4" from node_modules/@material-ui/pickers
| `-- react@17.0.1 deduped invalid: "^16.8.4" from node_modules/@material-ui/pickers
+-- react-scripts@4.0.2
| `-- react@17.0.1 deduped invalid: "^16.8.4" from node_modules/@material-ui/pickers
+-- react@17.0.1 invalid: "^16.8.4" from node_modules/@material-ui/pickers
`-- my-package@1.0.0 -> .\..\my-package
  +-- react-dom@17.0.2
  | `-- react@17.0.2 deduped
  +-- react-router-dom@5.3.0
  | +-- react-router@5.2.1
  | | +-- mini-create-react-context@0.4.1
  | | | `-- react@17.0.2 deduped
  | | `-- react@17.0.2 deduped
  | `-- react@17.0.2 deduped
  `-- react@17.0.2

npm ERR! code ELSPROBLEMS
npm ERR! invalid: react@17.0.1 C:\filepathtoproject\my-project\node_modules\react

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\filepathtologs\_logs\2021-10-05T17_30_51_332Z-debug.log
```

Which gave this log:

```
0 verbose cli [
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
0 verbose cli   'ls',
0 verbose cli   'react'
0 verbose cli ]
1 info using npm@7.20.3
2 info using node@v16.6.1
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 2ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 2ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 2ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
9 timing config:load:file:C:\filepathtoproject\my-project\.npmrc Completed in 1ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
11 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\{User}\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 1ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 8ms
19 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 8ms
20 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 0ms
21 timing npm:load:setupLog Completed in 1ms
22 timing npm:load:cleanupLog Completed in 2ms
23 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
24 timing npm:load:projectScope Completed in 1ms
25 timing npm:load Completed in 12ms
26 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 2ms
27 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
28 verbose shrinkwrap failed to load node_modules/.package-lock.json missing from lockfile: ../my-package/node_modules/ansi-regex
29 timing command:ls Completed in 1497ms
30 verbose stack Error: invalid: react@17.0.1 C:\filepathtoproject\my-project\node_modules\react
30 verbose stack     at LS.ls (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\ls.js:214:9)
30 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
31 verbose cwd C:\filepathtoproject\my-project
32 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
33 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "ls" "react"
34 verbose node v16.6.1
35 verbose npm  v7.20.3
36 error code ELSPROBLEMS
37 error invalid: react@17.0.1 C:\filepathtoproject\my-project\node_modules\react
38 verbose exit 1
```

For the sake of completeness, I have also included the rollup.config.js file from my latest attempt:

```
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel'
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve'
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import alias from '@rollup/plugin-alias';

export default [
    {
        input: './src/index.js',
        output: [
            {
                file: 'dist/index.js',
                format: 'cjs',
                exports: 'named',
                sourcemap: true,
                strict: false
            }
        ],
        plugins: [
            babel({
                exclude: 'node_modules/**',
                presets: ['@babel/preset-react']
            }),
            resolve(),
            commonjs(),
            alias({
                entries: [
                    {find: 'react', replacement: './node_modules/react'}
                ]
            })
        ],
        external: ['react', 'react-dom', 'react-router-dom']
    }
]
```

I have included the package-lock.json is in the module, but this did not change this output. I have tried many different approaches including, various configurations, using straight babel, version changes, and I have even brought the code I am trying to make a package into the project to make sure it works. I am not sure what is going wrong or where to fix it. Any and all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have answered my own question. I used Jetbrain's Webstorm and the index.js file autocompleted the require statements like this:

```
const authorizationService = require("authorizationService);
```

When it needed to be:

```
const authorizationSerivce = require("./authorzationService.js");
```

This fixed my module missing error.